# Calling Component Controller from VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

I have a VisualForce page with a list of objects on one side and a section on the right that shows details about the objects.  The section on the right is a VF Component.  The component controller has a method that looks up the details based on the object's ID.

The idea is when the user clicks on the list, the component updates.  Now, I know how to define an ActionFunction, and to call a method on the page controller via Javascript in response to the onclick.  But how do I call a method on the component controller to update the ID and have it reload it's data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to do so via an attribute on the component.

```
<apex:component controller="XYZ">
   <apex:attribute name="recordId" description="The record to view" assignTo="{!currentRecordId}" />
```

And in the controller:

```
public class XYZ {
    Id recordId;
    public void setCurrentRecordId(Id newRecordId) {
        if(newRecordId != recordId) {
            recordId = newRecordId;
            reloadData();
        }
    }
    // reloadData and related attributes not included
}
```

At that point, all you need to do is set the selected record Id in your page's controller/extension, and the assignTo function will notify your component of the change. Strictly speaking, you don't need an actionFunction, just a normal action method would work as well.

---

In the page:

```
<c:myComponent recordId="{!selectedRecordId}" />

...

<apex:repeat value="{!itemList}" var="item">
    {!item.name} <apex:commandLink action="{!item.selectRecordId}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

And in your controller:

```
public class pageController {
    public Id selectedRecordId { get; set; }
    public class Wrapper {
        pageController controller;
        public SObject record { get; set; }
        public void selectRecordId() {
            controller.selectedRecordId = record.Id;
        }
    }
    public Wrapper[] itemList { get; set; }
    // set itemList to the values for the wrapper
}
```

Comment: Hmmm.  I am doing pretty much exactly as you suggest.  But my page is not reloading.  I used an ActionFunction so I could specify exactly what to rerender.  I was under the impression that the component controller constructor (say that five times fast) would not be invoked again on the PostBack.  Not true?

Comment: @SalesForceJedi Constructors are not, but assignTo attributes are evaluated each time the component is rendered. Also, commandLink/commandButton both support reRender targets.

Comment: I see it now.  You specify the method, not the property in the attribute.  That's the missing piece.  Thanks so much!

Comment: To clarify: I was trying to do this in two steps 1) update the attribute value and 2) call some method to refresh the data.   Reading @sfdcfox's response I realized D'oh!  Just use a setter for the attribute and do both.  So my attribute:  <apex:attribute name="AppID" description="Selected appointment." required="false" assignTo="{!AppointmentID}" type="ID"/>  and in the controller:    private ID myID {get; set;}
 public ID AppointmentID
 {
  get {return myID;}
  set {
   if (myID!=value)
   {
    myID=value;
    if (myID==null) clearData();
    else getDetails();
   }
  }
 }